# How to move data analytics into AWS?

Tags: gooddata

I've installed tiger and I have one problem, I hope you could help me to solve it. Suppose I install tiger at a data center (physical datacenter) either using Docker and the AIO or Kubernetes. I get it installed, I connect to data sources, I do the ETL, I create the LDM, Metrics, Insights, Dashboard KPI. However, I realized that we need to have a cloud strategy and we need to move our data analytics - on premise Tiger - to AWS.  Can I shutdown then the docker image or kubernetes, SCP it to either 1. AWS EC2 instance OR 2. AWS EKS. Can someone walked me theoretically through these steps?
I suppose that datasources are not on yet on AWS and that there is a VPN connection between the on premise data center and AWS or even AWS Direct Connect between on premise data center and AWS Region for customer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are thinking about moving Tiger but not data source, it would be definitely challenging because of the latency (and also security).
Well, if a customer has good and secure link  between public cloud and on-premise, then it should work.
In such a case both deployments of Tiger can work fully in parallel, on top of the same data source. So such a migration would be almost zero-downtime.